# How to fix "Cannot run with sound null safety" error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, dependencies, null-safety

I'm encountering the following error in my Flutter project (Android Studio):

```
Error: Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies don't support null safety:

* package:fl_chart
* package:equatable
* package:path_drawing
* package:path_parsing

For solutions, see https://dart.dev/go/unsound-null-safety
```

How can I resolve this issue and run my project?

Comment: Take a backup of the project and run flutter pub upgrade in terminal. or add latest versions of these packages in pubspec.yaml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I search pub.dev for the packages, I see all the mentioned packages support null safety. You just need upgrade the version of packages.
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions